# Aptana content assist, DOMDocument PHP

Tags: php, aptana, content-assist

I have something like:

```
$elements = $document->query(...);
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $element -> //I want content assist
}
```

But Aptana (Studio 3, build: 3.5.0.201401092130) is not giving me the content assist.
if I do something like

```
$e = new DOMNode();
$e -> //content assist
```

then I'm getting the content assist.

How can I get it to work on the `$element` in the foreach?

Comment: Is `query()` a custom function? How do you define `$document`?

Comment: That's a `DOMXPath`. I really just need to know how to tell Aptana that `$element` is a `DOMNode`

Comment: If something like `$document = new DOMXPath()` doesn't register `$document` as `DOMXPath` instance (or `DOMXPath::query()` is not registered with `DOMNodeList` return type) it really feels like an IDE bug. Whatever, I've posted an answer with a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an Aptana user but most decent IDEs allow type hinting with this syntax:

```
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    /* @var $element DOMNode */
    $element -> //I want content assist
}
```

... or, some times, this variation:

```
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    /* @var DOMNode $element  */
    $element -> //I want content assist
}
```